# Update query giving error ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: database

Trying to update a column  `FCN_FILELIST_MASK` which is `varchar2(255)`.
 I am using below query.

`update file_collection set FCN_FILELIST_MASK='Concatenate( '*.*', NullString() )' where FCN_ID=6;`

i am getting below error:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00936: missing expression

But if i am firing below query its working fine :
`update file_collection set FCN_FILELIST_MASK='*.*' where FCN_ID=6;`

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

You are quoting the function so it interpret that `'Concatenate( '` is what you want to set and then it see a dot and became the error as it don't know what to do with it (as it isn't a expression).

Try doing:

```
update file_collection set FCN_FILELIST_MASK=Concatenate( '.', NullString() ) where FCN_ID=6;
```